# storing input in array, using sentinel value to exit loop, displays some stats Python

Tags: python, user-input, sentinel

I am having to press 0 twice before exiting the loop and I need to print mean salary and all salaries within 5k of mean.  HELP A NOVICE?!

#This program takes an employee name followed by their salary as input
#Using a sentinel value, the user is able to continue to enter names and salaries until
#pressing 0 to quit.  Then it is supposed to print the average  salary and the contents of the array.

#MY CODE IS SLOPPY.  ILL TAKE SUGGESTIONS ON IMPROVEMENT. THANK YOU!

```
from statistics import mean
import sys

names = []
salaries = []
e = None
s = None
running = True


def Main():
    e = None
    s = None
    count = 1
    while running == True:
        e = input(f"Enter Employee {count} Name      (press 0 to quit):  ")
        s = float(input(f"Enter Employee {count} salary (in hundreds)      (press 0 to quit):  "))
        L = [e, s]
        if e == 0 or s == 0:
            print(names)
            sys.exit()

       # print(statistics.mean(names))
        count = count + 1
       # print(statistics.mean(namees.append(L)))
        salaries.append(L)
```

Main()

Comment: `e` is a string, it must be compared to a string (`'0'`) and it is currently compared after the salary input. You could add a separate `if` directly after the name was entered.

Comment: Michael Butscher, I have the loop working correctly, but I cannot get exit the loop properly and have it print what I want.

  while e != 0:
        try:
            e = input(f"Enter Employee {count} Name      (press q to quit):  ")
            s = float(input(f"Enter Employee {count} salary (in hundreds)      (press q to quit):  "))
            L = [e, s]
        except:
            print(L)
            print(statistics.mean(salaries))
            quit = input("Press q to quit and display results")

Comment: @Shawngilbert107 you could just use a `break` statement to break out of the loop - https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/#the-python-break-and-continue-statements

Comment: Okay so I have to loop working but for some reason it will not import statistics to calculate the mean.  I also need to display anyone within 5 of mean.  Not sure why it wont import

Answer (score 0):

I would reformat your code like so:

```py
from statistics import mean
import sys

names = []
salaries = []
e = None
s = None


def Main():
    global e, s, names, salaries  # make sure we use the global variables instead of creating local ones
    count = 1
    while True:  # no need for a variable when the only exit condition is breaking out of the loop!
        e = input(f"Enter Employee {count} Name      (press 0 to quit):  ")
        if e == '0':
            break
        s = float(input(f"Enter Employee {count} salary (in hundreds)      (press 0 to quit):  "))
        if s == 0.0:
            break

        L = [e, s]         # is this useful?
        names.append(L)    # names.append(e) ?
        salaries.append(L) # salaries.append(s) ?
        count += 1

    print(names)
    print(statistics.mean(names))  # mean(salaries) ?
```

So the program also breaks when the user inputs 0.

Comment: It probably should be `salaries.append(s)` (not L) and then later `statistics.mean(salaries)` ?

Comment: Probably true, but I'm just sticking to what is in OP's post. Will add that as a comment though.